# What is a good non-melee class to play in coop Titan Quest?

Tags: titan-quest

I'm a relatively inexperienced TQ player. I've always found the game too easy at the start, and hence, too boring to play past Act 1. Up until now, I've played a Warden (Hunting + Defense).

This time, I'm playing coop with a friend, who will probably play a magic class, almost certainly including Spirit (mentioning this for potential synergies). We will use a mod that increases the difficulty immensely and heavily penalizes character death. To mix it up, I want to play a non-melee class. I've read about Ternion builds that are powerful, but using a single overpowered attack doesn't sound very fun.

What is a reasonably strong non-melee class for a new player who can't gear farm on a separate main and may not want to do the repetitive routine on his only character? It's not necessarily a gamebreaker, just something fun to play that is feasible and reasonably gear-independent. It doesn't also have to be a pure mage, a lot of people enjoy archery or beastmasters, it just has to be non-melee.

Comment: I would recommend removing the "please recommend" portion and making it more like your title question to avoid closure. Recommendations are generally frowned upon here.

Comment: I see your point, but it's general enough to work for other people as well (hopefully this is the reason for no close votes this far, and not the niche status of the tag...).
I am trying to edit it, but it ends up the same question with a more political phrasing. If you can improve, please do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while since I played TQ, but I remember having great fun playing an elementalist(storm/earth) build focused around Squall.  Squall is such a good spell since it makes all ranged attacks miss (huge bonus for a weak caster), and has great aoe.

If your friend is planning to be a tank for you, then going high DPS with Brigand (hunter/rogue) and a bow is not a bad idea but you won't have much survivability.

I know you said you want a non melee class, but if your friend is not going to be a tank you most certainly will want more survivability, and the Templar(dream/defense) is one of my favorite TQ classes of all time.